# angularjs date format with date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

```html
<input class="pw-form-control-text" 
       datepicker="" 
       id="requestedDate" 
       name="requestedDate" 
       ng-model="formData.requestedDate" 
       pattern="MMMM d, yyyy" 
       type="text" />
```

as you see this is a date picker when I select a date from the date picker it shows according to the directory. But when I sent value from the controller(its a string -

> 2014-08-06T13:52:39Z

) it shows the same string. it doesnt format according to the given format.
can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript code :

```
$( ".pw-form-control-text" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MMMM d, yyyy' });
```

Answer (score 0):

which extension you're using for date input?

whats about using [angularjs date input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) or [angular-ui-date](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date)?

Comment: the problem is when I select from the date picker it works nicely.. but when I set value to "$scope.formData.requestedDate" in controller it doesnt format according to the value.

Comment: what a datepicker you are using?? have you test it to send a date object instead of a string from controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directive, ng-change="changeformat()"

```
<input class="pw-form-control-text" 
       datepicker="" 
       id="requestedDate" 
       name="requestedDate" 
       ng-change="changeformat()"
       ng-model="formData.requestedDate" 
       pattern="MMMM d, yyyy" 
       type="text" />
```

And declare the function in your controller .js file as,

```
$scope.changeformat = function () {

       $scope.formData.requestedDate = $filter('date')($scope.formData.requestedDate, "MMMM d, yyyy");
    };
```